# How to use whereHas in laravel to find rows which id is equal to parent_row.id?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following database structure:

```
scripts (id, parent_id, name)
tasks (id, script_id, name)
```

I need to find all tasks that are available to execute by following query:

- where task has script with `parent_id = null`
- where `tasks.script_id = scripts.parent_id`

But how to do that in laravel way? What I have now:

```
$task = Task::query()
            ->where(function(Builder $query) {
                $query
                    ->whereHas('script', fn (Builder $childQuery) => $childQuery->where('parent_id', null))
                    ->orWhereHas('script', fn (Builder $childQuery) => $childQuery->where('parent_id', "I have no idea what should I put here"));
            })
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to make Eloquent Relationship between tasks and scripts model then in controller

```
$task = Task::with('scripts')->whereHas(function($query){
$query->where('parent_id','=',null)
});
```